# angular controller not returning result

Tags: angularjs, launching-application, supervisingcontroller

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src=angular.js></script>
<script src=app.js></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="mainController">
{{name}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js file

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);
var mainController = function($scope){
$scope.name="peter";    
}
```

I must get a return of name "peter" but unfortunately I am not getting that. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Checking your console for errors would have given you something to search for

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `app.js` as below:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', [$scope, function($scope) {
    $scope.name="peter"; 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to be dependent on module

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name="peter"; 
}]);
```

here is the workin [`Plnker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/ztwe62itbIOn38l2NiRb?p=preview)